# Where to find missing pages from "The Spice Cookbook"?

Tags: resources, cookbook

I purchased *The Spice Cookbook* by Lillie Stuckley at a thrift shop.  Awesome book, but it's in bad shape and is missing a few pages..

How can I find them? Without buying a whole new copy?

Comment: By Lillie Stuckley?

Comment: Yes that's the one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Borrow it from [The Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/spicecookbook0000avan), or from your local library, and copy out the missing pages.